# Jquery bootstrap datepicker not taking modal as it's parent

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, knockout.js, playframework

I have a bootstrap modal that scrolls, I know content is too long for it to be modal but nothing I can do about that.

The problem is I have a jQuery datepicker within that modal but it's taking the body as the parent and only scrolls with the body rather than the modal. I want the datepicker to stay in its place when scrolling in the modal.

I've tried a few tricks with the modal's position from fixed to absolute but it's not going to work if the datepicker takes the body as it's parent.

The modal is being called by MVC:

```
@Helpers.modal_common(
  modalId = "someid", 
  modalTitle = "sometitleforthemodal"
 ) {
```

I am calling the datepicker:

```
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3"> Date: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-5" data-bind="validationOptions:{ insertMessages: false }">
            <div class='input-group date' data-bind="newdatetimepicker: expiry,
                     dateTimePickerOptions: {format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', pickTime: false}">
              <input type='text' readonly class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>                
          </div>
```

The newdatetimepicker code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.newdatetimepicker = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
     allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
     var options = {
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
          defaultDate: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())
      };
 ko.utils.extend(options, allBindings.dateTimePickerOptions)
$(element).datetimepicker(options).on("change.dp", function (evntObj) {
  var observable = valueAccessor();
  if (evntObj.timeStamp !== undefined) {
    var picker = $(this).data("DateTimePicker");
    var d = picker.getDate();
    observable(Date.parse(d));
  }
 });
 },
   update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
     var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
     $(element).data("DateTimePicker").setDate(value);
    } 
  };
```

Here is a codepen example of what I am talking about http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNWvRv

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker control uses fixed positioning to place the popup at the location needed in relation to the datepicker trigger. Fixed positioning means it stays in the same place on the screen no matter where the content is scrolled. If you try to override the positioning, you're going to find that the behavior starts getting weird.

Why would you want the datepicker to scroll as you scroll? If you're scrolling and want the control to potentially scroll off-screen, you probably don't need it open anyways.